# Cloning Objects Doubling Every Time It Clones?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a rouge like and I'm trying to develop a shooting system. I'm making an original bullet off screen and duplicating that and for now I'm placing it at the middle for testing. And I make it duplicate it but whenever it duplicates it doubles the amount of the object how could I fix   this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Rigidbody2D bullet;
    public Transform parent;

    // parent is an empty gameobject that holds the bullet clones

    Vector2 movement;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void Update()
    { 
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            Debug.Log("Shot Left");
            Instantiate(bullet, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity, parent);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            Debug.Log("Shot Right");
            Instantiate(bullet, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity, parent);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
        {
            Debug.Log("Shot Down");
            Instantiate(bullet, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity, parent);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            Debug.Log("Shot Up");
            Instantiate(bullet, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity, parent);
        }   
    }


}
```

Comment: What are you parenting the instantiated object to?

Comment: a empty gameobject called parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just generating new bullets too fast. If you press two of those keys at the same time, two bullets will be generated. Try putting a delay after each bullet is created to prevent generating too many instances.

Also consider using Input.GetAxis() to read the keys as it's more dynamic and it will tie you to using a keyboard.

Finally, instead of having an original bullet object copy off screen, make a GameObject property on the script and assign the bullet prefab or asset directly into this property from the Editor. This saves memory.